# Most efficient way to query a word & synonym table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a `WORDTB` table with words and their synonyms: `ID, WORD1, WORD2, WORD3, WORD4, WORD5`. These words are arranged according to their frequency. When any word is given I want to query and retrieve the most frequent synonym of that particular word which is the word in `WORD1` column.

This is the query I tried and it works fine, but I think this is inefficient.

```
SELECT WORD1 
FROM WORDTB 
WHERE WORD1='xxxx' 
   OR WORD2='xxxx' 
   OR WORD3='xxxx' 
   OR WORD4='xxxx' 
   OR WORD5='xxxx'
```

Can anyone suggest a more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm using sqlite3.

Comment: @jarlh Actually I'm using words from Sinhala language native language of Sri lanka. So I think sample data will not make any sense. If in english data will be (1, start, beginning, inception)

Comment: Currently you have a table with 5 columns. What do you do when there are 6 synonyms?

Answer (score 0):

A more scalable solution would be to use a single row for each word.

```
synonym_words(word_id, synonym_id, word, popularity)
```

Fields:

- **word_id**: The primary key for a word.
- **synonym_id**: The word_id of the first synonym word.
- **word**: The synonym text.
- **popularity**: The sort order for the list of synonyms, 1 being the most popular.

Sample table data:

```
word_id | synonym_id | word       | popularity
==============================================
1       | 1          | start      | 1
2       | 1          | begin      | 2
3       | 1          | originate  | 3
4       | 1          | initiate   | 4
5       | 1          | commence   | 5
6       | 1          | create     | 6
7       | 1          | startle    | 7
8       | 1          | leave      | 8
9       | 9          | end        | 1
10      | 9          | ending     | 2
11      | 9          | last       | 3
12      | 9          | goal       | 4
13      | 9          | death      | 5
14      | 9          | conclusion | 6
15      | 9          | close      | 7
16      | 9          | closing    | 8
```

Assuming that the words will not change but their popularity may over time, the query should not break if you were to change the popularity order of the words so that the most popular synonym for a word was changed. You want your query to return the most popular word (popularity = 1) which shares the same synonym_id as the word used in the search.

SQL query:

```
SELECT word FROM synonym_words
WHERE synonym_id = (SELECT synonym_id FROM synonym_words WHERE word = 'conclusion')
AND popularity = 1
```